# Replace HTML element with function

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to replace the page_title div with the content of the `name` property. Below is what I have so far but it does not work. I'm new to jQuery any help. I'm using jquery Mobile.

```
 <script>
var siteData = {
    "name": "Site Name",
    "logo": "",
    "theme": "b",
    "fullSiteLink": "http://www.google.com",
    "pages": [{
            "id": "1364668689503",
            "name": "Page Title",
            "type": "basic",
            "components": {
                "img": "",
                "text": "Page content"
            }
        },
    }]
}
</script>
```

UPDATE

```
 $(document).ready(function(siteData) {
     //site name
     $('#page_title').html(siteData["name"]);
 });
```

Comment: Try siteData["name"] instead of site["name"]

Comment: So I have updated the question, but it still does not pull in name from the json. Instead it's now blank in the html markup.

Comment: There is nothing related to JSON in you question. JSON is a *data exchange format*, like XML. What you have a is simple object literal. Please be specific about what *"does not work"*. This is not a useful problem/error description.

Comment: @markO I made an edit to your question.

Comment: @yckart: You might have removed exactly the part which is the reason the OP's code did not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working **jsFiddle** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/gMAf3/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){      
    $(this).find('[data-role="header"] h3').html(siteData.name);
});

     var siteData = {


         "name": "Site Name",
             "logo": "",
             "theme": "b",
             "fullSiteLink": "http://www.google.com",
             "pages": [
         {
             "id": "1364668689503",
             "name": "Page Title",
             "type": "basic",
             "components": {
                 "img": "",
                 "text": "Page content"
             }
         }     ]


     }
```

Don't use document ready with jQuery Mobile, it will usually trigger before page is inserted into the DOM. To find more about this problem take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Comment: Given that you're not changing the HTML, why not simply use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)?

Comment: In this case I can use it because it is a plain text. Reason for html() is just to be on a safe side, people usually don't understand difference between text() and html(). So when they start dynamically building jQM page with a text() there's a problem.

Comment: Well, since it [doesn't make any significant difference](http://jsperf.com/brief-look-at-html-vs-text), anyway, it's not really worth worrying about I guess. Was just curious, really. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Declare the object here
    var siteData = {....};

    // Set the title
    $('#page_title').text(siteData["name"]);
});
```